# How to get object from nested entities in Spring/JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have this entities:

```
public class AnswerEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    private UserEntity user;
    @ManyToOne
    private AnswerDirectoryEntity answer;
    @ManyToOne
    private QuestionEntity question;
}
```

```
public class QuestionEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    private QuestionnaireEntity questionnaire;
}
```

```
public class QuestionnaireEntity  {
    private String code;
}
```

I need to take all user answers by `user ID` and corresponding `code` from `QuestionnaireEntity`.

I do it by create query like this:

```
List<AnswerEntity> answerList = answerRepository.findAllByUserId(userId);
```

and iterate over each object in my list and with using `equals` I compare each object to my questionnaire code:

```
for(AnswerEntity answerEntity : answerList){
            if(answerEntity.getQuestion().getQuestionnaire().getCode().equals(questionnaireId)){
     ///
}
```

but this solution is very slow because it must iterate each object from my database,

can anybody tell my how to create an `query` in my repository which can help me?

Comment: Is there any relation defined between entities ?

Comment: @Eklavya yes, i edit main post

Comment: You just want to check with `questionnaireId` and get only those `answerEntity ` ? or fetch all then do some operation

Comment: Define a query the fetches the user including question and questionaire. In JPQL this would be something like ```select a from AnswerEntity a join fetch a.question q join fetch q.questionnaire.``` Or write a query that contain's your "if" statement in the where clause. like  ```select a from AnswerEntity a join a.question q join q.questionnaire qu where qu.code=yourCode``` (haven't tried the statements, may need some fine tuning)

Comment: @TomStroemer i don't want to use this JPQL but i want to create a queries in repositories

Comment: @Eklavya I want to get all answers from ```answerEntity``` by user ID and code from ```questionnaire entity```

Comment: @Piotrek Why you are removing details of your question? If it's solved then accept the answer or post your better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JPA method query this way in repository

```
List<AnswerEntity> findByUserIdAndQuestionQuestionnaireCode(Integer userId, String code);
```